# custom User agent in chrome from menu in linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, gnome

I need to set a custom user agent in chrome on a linux system (gnome desktop). I know this is possible from the commandline using the --user-agent= option but I want to do this when the user selects chrome from the menu options in gnome . Is there some config file in gnome that can be modified to add this string when they open chrome

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Chrome's sandboxing is such that plugins cannot interact with the UA, however this can be done by getting the Chromium source and editing the code to include this.